# In Android: How do you show layout twice using intent?

Tags: android, layout, android-activity, android-intent

Let's pretend this was my Java Class...

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button ScreentwoGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screentwo);
    ScreentwoGameButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent ScreentwoGameIntent = new Intent(Main.this, Screentwo.class);
            startActivity(StartGameIntent);
        }
    });
```

How do i use this code below but the right way like.
So let's put an example if I click screentwo button the screentwo.xml will show and it will allow me to click inside if any buttons are available. Instead just stare what's in the layout.

I don't want to use the Activity to activity cause the whole point is i'm trying to avoid the flashing looking feel going to another java class.

If you look at the moron test game on Android it says example: press the blue button then red and then green, so if u press the blue button the screen will remain and not flash at all but the image of the blue button will disappear and I'm allowed to click the red and then green.
Hope that helped.

Thanks
Wahid

```
    Button ScreentwoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.screentwo);
    ScreentwoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        private Uri Uri;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView(R.layout.Screentwo);

            Uri uri=Uri;
            Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            mSoundManager.playSound(1);
        }
    });
```

Comment: please improve asking technique

Comment: I don't know how I understand your question, but try if this is your stuff, I think for this purpose make a new Layout on the your main.xml's layout set it visibility is gone on whenever you click on the screenTwoButton just set it visibility is VISIBLE and main.xml's main layout's visibility make GONE.

Comment: > I don't know how I understand your question, but try if this is your
> stuff, I think for this purpose make a new Layout on the your
> main.xml's layout set it visibility is gone on whenever you click on
> the screenTwoButton just set it visibility is VISIBLE and main.xml's
> main layout's visibility make GONE.

Sorry is it possible someone can give me a sample code of this...
I'm not good in creating codes as im learning still (beginning Android developer).


Thanks and sorry for confusing people on the start.

Answer (score 0):

try to use: 
`setContentView(R.layout.next layout);` in your button click.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the viewflipper class and add the different layouts as childs to the viewflipper 
and set the active child. Using setcontentView will be trouble some when you use findViewById for a old layout. As findViewById will look in the layout that is specified by setContentView